Intuition behind the formula: $(ah, bk) = (a, b)(h,k) (\frac{a}{(a,b)}, \frac{k}{(h,k)}) (\frac{b}{(a,b)}, \frac{h}{(h,k)})$
Recently, I've tried to derive $$(ah, bk) = (a, b) \cdot (h,k) \cdot \left(\frac{a}{(a,b)}, \frac{k}{(h,k)}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{b}{(a,b)}, \frac{h}{(h,k)}\right).$$ I think I succeeded but it got really messy.
I realize that it suffices to show
\begin{align}
    \min(A+H, B+K) &= \min(A+B) + \min(H + K) + \min(A-\min(A, B), K-\min(H,K)) \\ &+ \min(B-\min(A, B), H-\min(H,K))
\end{align} (then one can use the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic).
Then without loss of generality, I assumed $A+H≤B+K$ and dealt with some cases individually. It works (or at least I hope it does) but it doesn't really give the intuition as for why such formula should hold. Any better explanation for this formula, some intuition as to why this formula holds?

It follows simply & immediately by  homogenous reduction to the coprime case, see the linked dupe.

To discover it simply apply the gcd distributive law to factor out obvious common factors - see the Remark in the linked dupe.
